# Android ADB Open URL in current tab/close previous tabs

Tags: android, adb

I am currently using the following to open a tab in the native browser on an android device

```
adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.VIEW" -d "http://google.co.uk"
```

The issue I have is that each time the command is sent it open a new tabs. To combat this I have tried to kill the browser in an attempt to start again howevre, the previous tab are remembered.

```
adb shell am  force-stop com.android.browser
```

I did previously try a kill, but this did not seem to work

```
adb shell am kill com.android.browser
```

I did some quick reading and found the option `create_new_tab` but I believe this to be for chrome and not the native browser.

```
adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.VIEW" -d "http://google.co.uk" --ez create_new_tab false
```

Does anyone know how a single tab can be used and either open a tab if one does not exist, or use the existing one if it does. I am using windows command line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to reuse the same browser tab with the following command:

```
adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.VIEW" -d "http://www.google.com" --es "com.android.browser.application_id" "com.package.name"
```

Some documentation can be found here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Browser.html#EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID

Comment: For some reason this is still opening new tabs for me, I am trying variations but so far no joy

Comment: Scrap that, changed "com.package.name" to "com.android.browser" and now everything works perfectly. Many thanks for the solution.